# User/Search Paging not working suddenly

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I was using Twitter's User/Search API with no problem:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json
```

and

```
?q=myusername&count=20&page=3
```

But from yesterday, the paging property seemed not to work.

when I change `page` value, it returns the same page 1 results.

I even tested my query with https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/ but nothing changed.

I'm sure that I'm not doing anything wrong because it was working yesterday. So what happened?

Thanks for your help.

### Edit:

Well it seems something's wrong with twitter REST API:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/rest-api-people-search-json-not-returning-verified-accounts/31381
https://twittercommunity.com/t/users-search-doesnt-show-up-some-verified-account/31388

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved now. It was a twitter bug (`PREL-11824`).

More info: https://twittercommunity.com/t/users-search-doesnt-show-up-some-verified-account/31388

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem has come back.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/search-problems-have-returned/32573/3

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it's back :(